# c/c++ integration and compilation - unresolved external symbol even tho defined

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I'm working with a C++ project which contains a c file as well (the c file compile option is /TC) , the project compiles, all well.

Then I need to use some Pinvokes therefor I need to compile the project with /clr but then I have to use /TP for the C file and when I do it yells for:

unresolved external symbol dtoa_grisu3
but that function is defined under the .c file, it only yells when I compile with /TP .

here is the header:

```
#pragma once

extern "C"
{

/// Converts the given double-precision floating point number to a string representation.
/** For most inputs, this string representation is the
    shortest such, which deserialized again, returns the same bit
    representation of the double.
    @param v The number to convert.
    @param dst [out] The double-precision floating point number will be written here
        as a null-terminated string. The conversion algorithm will write at most 25 bytes
        to this buffer. (null terminator is included in this count).
        The dst pointer may not be null.
    @return the number of characters written to dst, excluding the null terminator (which
        is always written) is returned here. */

int dtoa_grisu3(double v, char *dst);

}

#ifdef __cplusplus

#include <string>
std::string dtoa_grisu3_string(double v);

#endif
```

and here is the implantation (in the c file):

```
int dtoa_grisu3(double v, char *dst)
{
    int d_exp, len, success, decimals, i;
    uint64_t u64 = CAST_U64(v);
    char *s2 = dst;
    assert(dst);

    // Prehandle NaNs
    if ((u64 << 1) > 0xFFE0000000000000ULL) return sprintf(dst, "NaN(%08X%08X)", (uint32_t)(u64 >> 32), (uint32_t)u64);
    // Prehandle negative values.
    if ((u64 & D64_SIGN) != 0) { *s2++ = '-'; v = -v; u64 ^= D64_SIGN; }
    // Prehandle zero.
    if (!u64) { *s2++ = '0'; *s2 = '\0'; return (int)(s2 - dst); }
    // Prehandle infinity.
    if (u64 == D64_EXP_MASK) { *s2++ = 'i'; *s2++ = 'n'; *s2++ = 'f'; *s2 = '\0'; return (int)(s2 - dst); }

    success = grisu3(v, s2, &len, &d_exp);
    // If grisu3 was not able to convert the number to a string, then use old sprintf (suboptimal).
    if (!success) return sprintf(s2, "%.17g", v) + (int)(s2 - dst);

    // We now have an integer string of form "151324135" and a base-10 exponent for that number.
    // Next, decide the best presentation for that string by whether to use a decimal point, or the scientific exponent notation 'e'.
    // We don't pick the absolute shortest representation, but pick a balance between readability and shortness, e.g.
    // 1.545056189557677e-308 could be represented in a shorter form
    // 1545056189557677e-323 but that would be somewhat unreadable.
    decimals = MIN(-d_exp, MAX(1, len-1));
    if (d_exp < 0 && len > 1) // Add decimal point?
    {
        for(i = 0; i < decimals; ++i) s2[len-i] = s2[len-i-1];
        s2[len++ - decimals] = '.';
        d_exp += decimals;
        // Need scientific notation as well?
        if (d_exp != 0) { s2[len++] = 'e'; len += i_to_str(d_exp, s2+len); }
    }
    else if (d_exp < 0 && d_exp >= -3) // Add decimal point for numbers of form 0.000x where it's shorter?
    {
        for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) s2[len-d_exp-1-i] = s2[len-i-1];
        s2[0] = '.';
        for(i = 1; i < -d_exp; ++i) s2[i] = '0';
        len += -d_exp;
    }
    // Add scientific notation?
    else if (d_exp < 0 || d_exp > 2) { s2[len++] = 'e'; len += i_to_str(d_exp, s2+len); }
    // Add zeroes instead of scientific notation?
    else if (d_exp > 0) { while(d_exp-- > 0) s2[len++] = '0'; }
    s2[len] = '\0'; // grisu3 doesn't null terminate, so ensure termination.
    return (int)(s2+len-dst);
}
```

How can I compile the project with /clr and avoid the unresolved symbols error?

Comment: The issue here surely is that the .c file is getting compiled with /clr in effect.  That's not legal, /clr code must be C++ code.  Compiling C code with /clr is just wrong, you get the worst of both worlds.  Best way to segregate them is to create a static library project, move all of the native C and C++ source files into that project and build it without /clr.  Link it with your C++/CLI project.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I know I can't use /clr with .c, thats why I switched to /TP (to compile it as C++ file, which works), But I need to fix the unresolved error of that specific function and continue to code normally. I don't want to create a C++/CLI project if not absolutely necessary and in this case I can just write a wrapper for the function I need, given I fix this error.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. You want CLR but you don't want C++/CLI. Isn't that a contradiction.

Comment: if you are "compiling as C++" then stop using "extern C"

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `extern "C"` or include the relevant headerfile [preferred] to ensure that it gets the same name. The name gets mangled for C++ functions, but `extern "C"` will not have the name mangled, so calls that include the header will produce the "unmangled" name, where the function definition will have the mangled name -> linker can't find it.

Comment: Hey, I couldn't get to the bottom of what you saying, if you notice in the code I linked, there is "extern C" declaration before the function declaration.

Comment: deleting the extern C and including the header in the .c file worked well, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**What is the problem ?**

The `dtoa_grisu3` in `extern C` has **C linkage**

The `dtoa_grisu3` in C file has **C++ linkage**

They are different symbols, it means the definition in C file is not for the declaration in header file.

So after linking you will get "*unresolved external symbol*" error.

**Solution:**

Put them all in or out of `extern C`